# Watch change in nested property in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I have created a Simple State Management with Reactivity API

My Store file looks like the following:

```
import { reactive, watch  } from "vue";

const state = reactive({
   form : {
    service_id : null
   }
})

 watch('state.form.service_id', (newVal, oldVal) => {
     console.log('service changed');
 }, { deep: true });
 

export default {
  state, 
}
```

I am trying to watch the change in `state.form.service_id`, but I am getting the following error:

[Vue warn]: Invalid watch source:  state.form.service_id A watch source can only be a getter/effect function, a ref, a reactive object, or an array of these types

If I replace the watch code with the following, then it works.

```
 watch('state.form', (newVal, oldVal) => {
     console.log('form changed');
 }, { deep: true });
```

But I need to watch for the change in `state.form.service_id`. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to use a getter function instead of the property path :

```js
 watch(()=>state.form.service_id, (newVal, oldVal) => {
     console.log('service changed');
 }, { deep: true });
```